# Theorems on the Cauchy integral operator

Tags: complex-analysis

While reading on Cauchy's integral formula, I found the following two theorems on the Cauchy integral operator:

The first theorem states: Let $f$ be a complex function that is holomorphic in a region $U$. Let $\Delta_r(c)$ be a disk, which along with its boundary $\delta \Delta_r(c)$ is contained in $U$. For all $z \in \Delta_r(c)$ the following is true:
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\delta \Delta_r(c)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} d\zeta
\end{equation*}

The second theorem states: Let $f: \overline{\Delta_1(0)} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continous function which is also holomorphic in $\Delta_1(0)$. It holds for every $z \in \Delta_1(0)$ that
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\delta \Delta_1(0)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} d\zeta
\end{equation*}

The second theorem is given without proof. My question is whether the second statement holds for general disks and whether it can be proven using the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f \colon \overline{\Delta_R(c)} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and holomorphic on $\Delta_R(c)$. Then by the first theorem, we have $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\delta \Delta_r(c)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} d\zeta$$ for all $r<R$. It should be clear that the right hand side depends continuously on $r$ so that we can take the limit $r \rightarrow R$ to get $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta \Delta_R(c)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} d\zeta.$$